# How can i get login time for user to my website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can i get last login time for user to my website ?!

I have a login page login.aspx as a default page and welcome.aspx page which direct user after login to welcome.aspx page

i want in welcome.aspx page to display  time that user login to website in a lable control

PLEASE HELP ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options (cookies, session, database..)

**Cookies**:
Cookies might be simple enough for you. When your user logs in, you can create a cookie in Login.aspx (before redirect) like:

```
HttpCookie _infoCookie = new HttpCookie("InfoCookie");
_infoCookie["LoginDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
Response.Cookies.Add(_infoCookie);
```

You can then read this cookie at Welcome.aspx

```
var loginDate = Request.Cookies["InfoCookie"]["LoginDate"];
```

*beware: Cookies can be easily read, so don't save any sensitive data in them (like password..)*

**Session**:
*It can be also done by session as mentioned. Here's how:*

saving to session (in Login.aspx):

```
Session["LoginDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

reading from session (in Welcome.aspx):

```
var loginDate = Session["LoginDate"];
```

Just a note: Sessions are safer and probably simpler to use + you don't have to notify users about cookies usage (in US, there's some law related to storing user data in cookies.. you basically have to let users know about it. Do not know details.)

edit: Forgot to actually add the cookie into Response object, fixed now :)

Comment: thankyou...but it shows an error like " Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Where exactly? Depending on specific implementation, you need to call .ToString() on the datetimes to get just a string representation that can be further used in controls properties.

Comment: @DIVYA HARI: If you were tryign the cookies implementation, I forgot one line there. It's fixed now so you can try again :)

Comment: in login.aspx it shows " can't implicitily convert datetime to string "

Comment: @DIVYA HARI: Use DateTime.Now.ToString() instead then. Only DateTime.Now does give you a DateTime object, but you are trying to assign it somewhere, where only a string is accepted, so you need to convert it first.

Comment: yeah..it shows "can't implicitily convert datetime to string "  error even after adding that line

Comment: @DIVYA HARI I've added ToString() directly into code. Try it now. If it still doesn't work, please edit your question and provide your current code. It's geting weird ;)

Answer (score 0):

save the login date and time in user session, and if you want to display the last user login in anther users page, you need to save these data into database.